# How can I make my iChat to connect again to chat server when I wake my Mac?

Tags: ichat

Currently, my iChat does not recover my status when Mac is waken from sleeping. It keeps being offline. How can I make it connect to server automatically when my Mac waken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iChat plugin [Chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/) will let you do this.

[image: Chax preferences]

Answer (score 0):

What version of iChat do you have? When I close my computer (thus putting it to sleep), and then reopen it, after 15 seconds or so, it reconnects. I have v5.0.3.  Check to see if you have that version, or whatever the newest version is. If that doesn't help, try reinstalling the program.

Comment: Mine is also `Version 5.0.3 (745)`. How can I reinstall iChat? Should I reinstall whole OS again?